# Save search options from advanced search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a advanced search form and I would like to present the users a option to save their options. How can I accomplish this?

The user should be able to fill out their options for the advanced search form, and click "Save this Search" link which will store their options. With this in place each user will have their custom default search options so each time they visit they won't have to reenter the details.

I think this would be helpful to a lot of people in the future.

Searches controller:

```
 def new
    @search = Search.new
    render layout: 'new_application'
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
        redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @users = @search.users
    render 'users/index', layout: 'new_application'    
  end

  def update
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    if @search.update_attributes(params[:search])
        redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    if location = Location.find_by_zipcode(params[:search])
        latitude  = location.latitude * Math::PI / 180 
        longitude = location.longitude * Math::PI / 180 

        locations = Location.search( 
          :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..600_000.0}, 
          :order => 'geodist ASC',
          :per_page => 5_000
        ) 
        @users = User.where(zip_code: locations.map(&:zipcode))


          else
            @users = User.search(params[:search])
        end      
      end

  def min_age
    @min_age = params[:min_age].to_i.years
  end

  def max_age
    @max_age = params[:max_age].to_i.years
  end

  def youngest_age
  @youngest_age = params[:youngest_age].years
  end

  def oldest_age
  @oldest_age = params[:oldest_age].years
   end
end
```

Search model:

```
 def users
    @users ||= find_users
  end

    private

    def find_users
      users = User.order(:id)
      users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
      users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
      users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
      users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
      users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?

      if min_age.present? && max_age.present?
        min = [ min_age, max_age ].min
        max = [ min_age, max_age ].max
        min_date = Date.today - min.years
        max_date = Date.today - max.years
        users = users.where("birthday BETWEEN ? AND ?", max_date, min_date)
        users
      end
      users
    end
  end
```

Search form:

```
  a.adv_search href="#" 
    = image_tag "adv_link.png"
    span Advanced Search
  = form_for @search do |f|
    .form_container
      .row
        .col
          label I am a
          select.large
            option Female
            option Male
        .select2
          .col.col2
            label Seeking
            = f.select :gender, %w(Female Male)
        .select1
          .col.col3
            label Ages
            = f.select :min_age, options_for_select((18..50),25), {}, {class: 'small'}
        .select5
          .col.col4
            label to
            = f.select :max_age, options_for_select((20..50),45), {}, {class: 'small'}
      .row
        .col.col5
          label Near
          = f.text_field :zip_code,placeholder: "enter zip here", class: 'text_input'
        .col.col6
          = f.select :children, ['I want kids now','I want one someday'], prompt: 'child preference'

        .select4
          .col.col6
            = f.select :religion, ['Agnostic', 'Atheist', 'Christian', 'Catholic', 'Buddhist', 'Hindu', 'Jewish', 'Muslim', 'Spiritual without affiliation', 'Other', 'None', 'Prefer not to say'], prompt: 'Religion'
        .select4
          .col.col7
            = f.select :ethnicity, ['Asian', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other'], prompt: 'Ethnicity'
      .btm_sec
        ul.form_list
          li
            a href="#" 
              = image_tag "form_icon1.png"
              span.color Save this Search
          li
            a href="#" 
              = image_tag "form_icon2.png"
              span Load
          li
            a href="#" 
              = image_tag "form_icon3.png"
              span Reset
        input.find_btn type="submit" value="Find" /
    .btm_search_detail
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have to store them in a model, the best thing is to store in a serialized hash.  I've done this for an app where I needed admins to save their preferences/settings.  I've tried acouple gems, in the end I used [rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings).

Ie, in your User model, you'd do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_settings do |s|
    s.key :search_options,  :defaults => { :gender => 'male'}
  end
end
```

Then to set/save settings, you can do:

```
user.settings(:search_options).gender = 'female'
user.save!
```

What I like about this approach is that it has a low foot-print, and if you ever start seeing scalability issues, then its very easy to strip it out and implement a full model for optimization.

Comment: I stumbled on this while repairing a broken Save Search feature, make sure that any serialized search params that you save are updated if the search form changes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Persistence**

I would personally look to persist your data within another associative model, like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :search
   delegate :input, :advanced, :options, to: :search, prefix: true
end

#app/models/search.rb
Class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | input | other | advanced | options | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This means that if you're able to populate the model from creating the "search" options, you will be able to create the required functionality you need

Now, as a caveat here, I don't know what your `Search` model does right now - but I'll detail how I would get it working *if* the `Search` model was just for my own ideas:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_search

   private

   def set_search
      @search_option = current_user.search_input if user_signed_in?
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to populate your forms with the advanced options specific to your user:

```
#app/views/shared/_search.html.erb
<%= form_tag search_path do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, value: @search_option %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

This will set the default options *if* the user is present

--

**Model**

Of course, this will mean you've got to create another model / database entry for your user. However, it also means that you can persist the options throughout different calls

Your description of having multiple "default" search parameters is one which I don't fully understand - but including a model to handle it will give you the ability to make sure the data remains persisted

To populate the `Search` model, you'd have to call / create the associative object when you create a new lookup:

```
#app/controllers/searches_controller.rb
Class SearchesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      current_user.search.create(input: params[:input], etc: "value") if params[:save_defaults].present?
   end
end
```

I suppose, after looking at your code, a more succinct way to mange it would be to **use an association** to manage the search objects :)